# Selecting all columns in DataFrame.set_index except one

Tags: python, pandas

As the title says, I'm trying to select all columns except one in `DataFrame.set_index`.

I tried the following way:

```
df = df.set_index(list(df.columns != 'cus_name'))
```

The `cus_name` Series is the one I want to exclude.  The above code raise a `KeyError: True`.

The `list(df.columns != 'cus_name')` is a list of boolean values `[True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]` and what I need is a list of columns names except the `cus_name`.

I know I could explicitly input the complete list of columns I want in the `set_index` method but I was wandering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try list comprehension

```py
df = df.set_index([c for c in df.columns if c != 'cus_name'])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`pd.Index.difference()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) here with `sort=False` if order is important:

```
df=df.set_index(df.columns.difference(['cus_name'],sort=False).tolist())
```

Answer (score 3):

A cheeky way to achieve this with set operations:

```
df.set_index(list(set(df.columns) - {'cus_name'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
df = df.set_index(df.columns.drop('cus_name').tolist()))
```